# If a sum equals zero how can I get awk to print another known value to the file

Tags: awk, replace, math

I have a numerous files in which I extract the total number of records and total number of missing files in order to compute data averages. I have numerous files where the number of missing records equals the total number of records.

This results in a 0 value and a 0 for the sum of the data for the file `Settotal.tmp`, and get the following error message `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=Settotal.tmp FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted`.

Unfortunately this halts my script. I have been tried numerous options to correct this issue. I figured that I could use an if statement to fix but are unable to make it work.

In this case since the sum is zero, I have attempted to force the value to equal Sum Total Records: 91. In this was I can bypass the 0 error and make the `Divsortotal.tmp` output file to be

{ sum of valid and missing(-999) data (corrected value): 91 }

input file  ( `Validpoints.tmp` ):

```
Sum Total Records: 91
Number of missing data: -91
```

```
awk -F ':' '{ sum+=$2 }; END { print "sum of valid and missing(-999) data (corrected value):" sum (if $2=0 {print NF==1 $2})}' Validpoints.tmp > Divsortotal.tmp
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: I understand that the above two lines file is the input of the modified script. Can you tell us the expected output, and the actual unexpected output?

Comment: The awk program at the end doesn't make much sense, actually. Perhaps it's a matter of formatting?

Comment: Based on this example is the number of "Sum Total Records" is the total number of days in a given season. However will be applied to various conditions, (i.e. All days in a given month * number of years...ect. In this case I am looking for when the (Sum Total Records:) and (Number of missing data:)  to be forced to the value of (Sum Total Records:). This would force the Divsortotal.tmp to always be "non-zero"

Comment: or 91 in this case. The next line in my script creates a file Settotal.tmp and for this case should look like.... ```sum of data(corrected value):0
# of all records:91```

Answer (score 0):

I will ignore the `awk` code in your question, because I don't quite understand it, and instead answer the question about outputting another value if the sum is zero.

To figure out whether the sum is zero, you would test it in an `if` statement:

```c
if (sum == 0) { ... }
```

So, you would get

```bsh
awk -F : '{ sum += $2 } END { if (sum == 0) print "sum = 543"; else printf "sum = %d\n", sum }' file
```

This outputs `sum = 543` whenever the sum is zero, and the actual sum in all other cases.

You could compress this slightly by using a single `printf` statement and instead pick the value that you use depending on the value of `sum`:

```bsh
awk -F '{ sum += $2 } END { printf "sum = %d\n", ( sum == 0 ? 543 : sum ) }' file
```

Here, `( sum == 0 ? 543 : sum )` is using the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) `?:` to evaluate to 543 if the sum is zero, and to the actual sum in all other cases.